# Makefile problems with gcc flags (file not recognized; shared libraries)

Tags: gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm a little confused now. I'm trying to get the Makefile work but it breaks. I Hope someone can help me with this bad and frustrating time-killer.

I've written a small and lightweight part of a Compiler.

> **The project has the following structure:**
>
> /Compiler.cpp
>   /Makefile
>   /Buffer/
>   /Buffer/Makefile
>   /Scanner/
>   /Scanner/Makefile
>   /SymTable/
>   /SymTable/Makefile

When I'm compiling Buffer, Scanner and SymTable manual (changing the directory and typing 'make mode=release' it's no problem and each shared-library is compiled). But when I run the Makefile from within where the 'Master Makefile' /Makefile is, it fails and the terminal prints something like:

```
Buffer/libBuffer.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: \*** [Compiler] Error 1
```

Here is the listing of the Makefile of /Buffer/Makefile (the same for Scanner and SymTable):

```
CXX = g++

ifeq ($(mode),release)
  CXXFLAGS = -g -fPIC -O3 -ffunction-sections -march=native
else
  mode = debug
  CXXFLAGS = -g3
endif

MODUL = Buffer
COMPONENTS = Buffer.h
MK_LIBRARY = lib$(MODUL).so

all: $(MK_LIBRARY)

$(MK_LIBRARY): $(COMPONENTS)
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $^

clean:
  rm -f $(MK_LIBRARY)

.PHONY: all
.PHONY: clean
```

The 'Master Makefile' looks like:
    CXX = g++

```
ifeq ($(mode),release)
  CXXFLAGS = -g -O3 -ffunction-sections -fwhole-program -march=native
else
  mode = debug
  CXXFLAGS = -g3
endif

TARGET = Compiler

COMPONENTS = $(TARGET)

DIRS = Buffer Scanner SymTable
MAKE = make
MFLAGS = mode=$(mode)

all: $(COMPONENTS)

$(TARGET): Compiler.cpp libBuffer.so libScanner.so libSymTable.so
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -IBuffer -IScanner -ISymTable \  
  -LBuffer -LScanner -LSymTable \  
  -lBuffer -lScanner -lSymTable -o $@ Compiler.cpp

libBuffer.so: force_look
  cd Buffer; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS)

libScanner.so: force_look
  cd Scanner; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS)

libSymTable.so: force_look
  cd SymTable; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS)

clean:
  rm -f $(COMPONENTS)
  @for d in $(DIRS); do (cd $$d; $(MAKE) clean ); done

check:
  @for d in $(DIRS); do (cd $$d; $(MAKE) check ); done

force_look:
  true

.PHONY: all
.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: check
```

I hope some has an answer for me! Thanks!

Comment: What is the command line that generates that error?  It should be printed immediately before the error message, and looking at what is wrong with it should tell you exactly what is wrong with the makefiles.  Also make sure to do a `make clean` to make sure you haven't left around corrupted intermediate files.  The apparent error is that Buffer/libBuffer.so is corrupted/not a valid shared library.

Answer (score 0):

There's something very weird about this part:

```
MODUL = Buffer
COMPONENTS = Buffer.h
MK_LIBRARY = lib$(MODUL).so

$(MK_LIBRARY): $(COMPONENTS)
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $^
```

This rule tries to build `libBuffer.so` out of *`Buffer.h`*, the header file. How can this possibly work, without the definitions of the things in `Buffer.cc`? I would do it this way:

```
lib%.so: %.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $^
```

**EDIT:**
You have the definitions of Buffer in `Buffer.h`? All right, you have more than one problem, and the only way to solve them is to do what almost always works: retreat to a simpler problem and solve that first. Can you make `Buffer.o`? And can you then link that into your executable (bypassing `libBuffer.so`)? And if not, can you write a "HelloWorld" in `Buffer/`, and link `Buffer.o` into *that*?

Comment: I've written the whole Buffer in the headerfile... so this works. I'll try your solution... Hm, okay but your solution doesn't work for me :(